# std::map sort by size of value (set<int>)

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, set, size

Using C++, I have a map with an int key and a set value.  I'd like to sort the map for output based on the size of the set (i.e., value.size()).  I know the map automatically sorts itself based on the key. Is there some way to make the map sort by number of elements in its value?  Also, if I flip the map, as some posts suggest, and the key becomes set, how does the map determine the sort order?  Any help understanding this would be much appreciated.

```
mymap<int, set<int> >;
/* code to fill map */
/* How to sort by mymap[node].second().size() ??? */
```

Comment: flip the map and use a custom comparator in the flipped map which considers size of the set when comparing.

Comment: You could sort a `vector` of pointers to `set`s that refer back into your `map`.

Comment: If it's sorted by the size (or any other other property) of the values, then it's no longer sorted by key, so it's no longer `std::map`. Is there some reason you want the container to be sorted by set size? Do you have any use for the key?

Comment: The project requires that the output be sorted by the size of the set associated with the key.  The key also must be output to a file, so I need them both.  I was thinking to switch the key to the set, but I'm not sure exactly what effect that would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the sort order of an existing `map`.

Illustrating one way to create an index into the `map` in the form of a sorted `vector`...

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> size_key;

for (auto& x : mymap)
    size_key.emplace_back(x.second.size(), x.first);
std::sort(std::begin(size_index), std::end(size_index));

// work's done above - just display the results to illustrate access...

for (auto& sk : size_key)
{
    std::cout << "with size " << sk.first
              << ", value " << mymap[sk.second].first << '\n';
    for (auto& n : mymap[sk.second].second)
         std::cout << "  " << n << '\n'
}
```

> Also, if I flip the map, as some posts suggest...

Not a good idea: just "flipping" key and value won't help without also changing the sort comparitor, you'd need a `multimap` if `set` sizes could be repeated, and slower and more wasteful of memory than building an index as above (unless you can throw away the original `mymap` once the re-ordered `multimap` is constructed).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try implementing this solution and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to *output* the map in some weird sorted order.

You should not want to modify the order of keys inside a `std::map` (that does not make any sense, since the fixed order -i.e. the key compare function - is the second template parameter of `std::map`).

So get the [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of keys from the [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/):

```
std::vector<int> keyvec;
keyvec.reserve(mymap.size());
for (auto&x : mymap)
  keyvec.push_back(x.first);
```

then sort (using [std::stable_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/) to keep keys of same size in original order) it according to your criteria

```
std::stable_sort(keyvec.begin(), keyvec.end(),
                 [&mymap,=](int k1, int k2) 
                 { return mymap[k1].size() < mymap[k2].size(); });
```

and at last *display* your map using

```
for (auto k: keyvec)
   std::cout << "[" << k << "]:" << mymap[k] << std::endl;
```